# Looking for AWS cloud environment management tool

Tags: amazon-web-services

Some time ago I found some open source tool (code on github) that allows to describe AWS cloud configuration in a file (yaml as I remember) - vpn, instances, load balancers, etc and then it allows to deploy/sync it on AWS easily. Unfortunately I did not add it to favourites and now I can't find this tool... I think there was a word "form" in this tool name. Maybe someone can help me OR please point me a better place to ask for it if stackoverflow is not the right place.

Comment: Are you looking for `CloudFormation`?

Comment: Nope, it was external (from AWS), open-source project

Answer (score -1):

Found it (thanks @Mahdi, CloudFormation helped me to find what I was looking for) - it's TerraForm https://www.terraform.io/